# Spring data jpa deleteAllByField not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am wondering why deleteAllByField is not working. This method is called in a @Transactional service layer. By logging hql queries with jpa nothing is logged.
Here is what the repository and service look like :

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo,Long> {
    void deleteAllByField(String field)
}

@Service
@Transactional
public FooService {
    @Autowired
    FooRepository fooRep;

    public void deleteAllByField(String field) {
        fooRep.deleteAllByField(field);
    }
}
```

When using built in deleteAll(), the record are deleted and I can see the hql query printed.

I added @Transactional on the repository’s method level and it worked.

I am confused. Can someone clarify this behavior please ?

Comment: Please add your code, otherwise it would be very hard to answer the question. Thanks!

Comment: If you're looking for a workaround you can use @Query

atModifying
atQuery("delete from Fruit f where f.name=:name or f.color=:color")

Comment: @JoãoDias thank you for replying. I added some code snippets :)

Comment: Your code should work even without `@Transactional` in the `deleteAllByField` method. Can you please try removing it but having `Long` as the return type of such method: `Long deleteAllByField(String field);`? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @joão, after investigations, I noticed that I created a custome transaction manager. After adding @Transactional(‘’customTransactionManager’’) on the service layer it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigations, I noticed that I created a custome transaction manager. After adding @Transactional(‘’customTransactionManager’’) on the service layer it worked.

Ps: I have a multi datasource configuration.